Verify.Attributes.cs(14,12): Error CS0579 : Duplicate 'VerifyXunit.UseVerifyAttribute' attribute
I recently added Verify for xUnit to my test project. Now it fails to compile:
Verify.Attributes.cs(14,12): Error CS0579 : Duplicate 'VerifyXunit.UseVerifyAttribute' attribute
I tried downgrading to the last minor version, but had no success. Also, it seems not to have caused a GitHub issue thus far.
Anyone found that and a solution?

xUnit now has an api that renders [UsesVerify] redundant.
It can be remove it from all tests
https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/pull/1131
